# Bind GruntJS commands

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am using uglify, compass and copy for GruntJS. Now I would like to bind all of them to one single command, so I don't have to type in "grunt uglify", "grunt compass" and "grunt copy", but instead only something like "grunt project". Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Yeah. http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`registerTask`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task) to create an alias around several tasks.

Example:

```
    grunt.initConfig({

            clean: /* ... */,
            copy: { /* ... */ },
            uglify: { /* ... */                }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'uglify','copy']);
```

Then just call `grunt build` (or whatever you choose to call it) from the command line.

Comment: the "default" task is called `default` and you just have to type `grunt` in your console to trigger it.